# Count down from user-defined amount of time

Tags: android, countdown

I have a working countdown, but it only counts down from a hard coded integer that I put in. I want the user to be able to type in a number and have it count down from that number instead. I want the text put into "timeedit" to be put into a string and put to the value of "startTime".

EDIT: If the code below is not indented correctly on your screen, you can also view the code here: http://pastebin.com/BnzEtFX5

Code:

```
public class TimerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
    private Button startB;
    public TextView text;
    public String time;
    private long startTime = 30 * 1000;
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
    private EditText timeedit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_countdown);
        startB = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        startB.setOnClickListener(this);
        text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
        timeedit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timeedit);
        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        time = timeedit.getText().toString();
        text.setText(time); //+ String.valueOf(startTime/1000)
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!timerHasStarted) {
            countDownTimer.start();
            timerHasStarted = true;
            startB.setText("STOP");
        } else {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            timerHasStarted = false;
            startTime = 30 * 1000;
            startB.setText("RESTART");
        }
    }


    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            text.setText("Time's up!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            text.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, what happened to your code indenting? That's really hard to read.

Comment: @GregHewgill:  A CTRL+ALT+L in IntelliJ and the problem is solved.  :P

Comment: @Makoto: Sure, for you. However, I've seen people actually try to write code without indenting, and the OP needs to know that's not okay.

Comment: @GregHewgill that's kinda weird because on my computer it shows it's indented correctly... Anyways, here's a link for you to see it easier. http://pastebin.com/BnzEtFX5

Comment: @ThatGuyThere: Well, Makoto already fixed this question so it appears appropriately indented. Don't forget to use the formatted preview when posting stuff on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm...I'm not sure what the problem is but if I understand you correctly, you just need to do something like this in `onCreate()`

```
String userTime = timeedit.getText().toString();
startTime = Long.parseLong(userTime);
```

**Edit**

you will actually want to put `startTime` and `userTime` in your `onClick`. If it is in `onCreate()` then your `EditText` will be empty unless you put a default value in your xml but either way it won't be what the user has entered. You also need to surround with a `try/catch` in case the user enters something other than numeric characters.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    String userTime = timeedit.getText().toString();
    long startTime = Long.parseLong(userTime);
    if (!timerHasStarted) {
        countDownTimer.start();
        timerHasStarted = true;
        startB.setText("STOP")
```

Comment: It's saying: invalid number exception: invalid long: ""

Comment: Yes, in my haste I forgot to add that you will need to do some error checking. You can surround it with a `try/catch` so that if `startTime` is an invalid `long` you can display a message to the user because you will get exceptions for empty strings, text, etc...

Comment: Okay, so using this code, I get no errors, but even when I type something, it still starts from 30 seconds, not the amount I type in. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the code "private long startTime = 30 * 1000;" but it gives me an "invalid long" error if I remove the "30 * 1000" part of it

Comment: Yes, get rid of that variable because you are moving it to the `onClick`. You want to use this user-defined variable now so get rid of the original and set this new one in `onClick` before starting the timer. But make sure to surround with 'try/catch' in case there is an invalid character in there

Comment: Okay, I did that and now the line "countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);" is giving me an error. I tried putting that in the onClick(); as well and it just force closes. I've made the edittext only take numeric input.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30665/discussion-between-thatguythere-and-codemagic)

Comment: @ThatGuyThere Sorry about the chat...something came up and I had to go. Let me know if you still need help

Answer (score 0):

If You want to let user do some input, you simply have to get this with:

```
    String userCountDown = timeEdit.getText().toString();
```

then parse it into Long:

```
    long userStartTime = Long.parseLong(userCountDown);
```

and then, pass it to the countDown

```
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(UserStartTime, interval);
```

But You have to be sure that the value inside your timeEdit is an Long value. By setting the attribute inputType="number" inside Your layout.xml file to the  R.id.timeedit, you can get sure to get an Long. But to be very sure that there is an input, You can do any check and show a warning for the user.

```
        if (!timerHasStarted) { 
              String userCountDown = timeEdit.getText().toString();
             if(userCountDown.length()<1){

                Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this,"PLEASE DO SOME INPUT",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }else{
                 long userStartTime = Long.parseLong(userCountDown);
                    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(userStartTime, interval);
                countDownTimer.start();
              timerHasStarted = true;
              startB.setText("STOP");
            }
       } else {

             countDownTimer.cancel();
             timerHasStarted = false;
              startTime = 30*1000;
              startB.setText("RESTART");
         }
```

Comment: `CountDownTimer` constructor and methods take `long` values not `int`. Also, you have some conflicting cases there with variable names

Comment: So, if I use your code, which I actually understand (hooray!), it almost works but for some reason it gives me an error where it says "startTime = 30*1000"

Comment: could you post the logcat, then we will see where exactly the issue is?

Comment: Okay, I used your code and got it working. However, whenever I press the start button, it always goes straight to the end, it doesn't actually count down. There's no error, so the log doesn't show much

Comment: have you deleted countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval); in onCreate() ? If not, do it....